# find the value of $k$ in the term $2^{-k} = 1/n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

What is the value of $k$ if I have the following equation: $2^{-k} = \frac1n$?

> $$2^{-k} = \frac 1 n \implies
> n = 2^k \implies \log_{2} n = k$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Do you know what a logarithm is?

Comment: I have n = 2^k => log_{2} n = k ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should [edit] your question to include this information and clarify exactly what the issue is; you've just about solved it already, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: $$(-k)\log{2} = \log{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: what do we know about the variables?

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted ? @T.Bongers I'm pretty sure OP wants to check whether his solution is correct or not... His post is pretty clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your solution is correct

> $$2^{-k} = \frac 1 n \implies
> n = 2^k \implies \log_{2} n = k$$

Answer (score -2):

$$k=\frac{\log\left(n\right)+2i\pi c_1}{\log\left(2\right)}$$
for any integer $c_1$, where $\log$ is the natural logarithm and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: @saisaandeep I disagree. Can you please prove your statement?

Comment: It's a bit confusive.